# CSE UDF VBA Returning only first element

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a UDF that returns an Array (CSE function).
In particular, the UDF receives a folder path and lists everything in it.

I think I am almost there because, when debugging the function does have all its array elements assigned to the values I want, but when doing Ctrl + Shift + Enter in the selected range on Excel it only shows the first element.

```
Function VBA_ListFilesIn(mypath As String) As Variant
Dim myArray() As String
Dim myArraySize As Integer

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

myArraySize = CountFilesInFolder(mypath)
ReDim myArray(1 To myArraySize)

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(mypath)

i = 1
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
myArray(i) = oFile.Name
If i < myArraySize Then
i = i + 1
End If
Next oFile
VBA_ListFilesIn = myArray

End Function
```

This is a snip of my locals right before End Function...
[image: This is a snip of my locals right before End Function]

CountFilesInFolder is this:
https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/vba-count-files-in-folder/

I looked around for this problem, but I could only find people having #VALUE, basically not reaching even this last step.

Note: Changing the return type of the function from variant to string() leads to the same problem.

It might have a very obvious solution, but I am quite lost for a while here.

Comment: Your array is 1 dimensional `(1 to 6)` but ranges are always 2 dimensional `(rows, columns)` even if it is just one row or one column there are 2 dimensions like `(1 to 6, 1 to 1)` means 6 rows 1 column. That is probably the issue you have there.

Comment: Thanks... I knew it was something not hard... I just could figure it out!

Comment: wrote it as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is 1 dimensional `(1 to 6)` but ranges are always 2 dimensional `(rows, columns)` even if it is just one row or one column there are 2 dimensions like `(1 to 6, 1 to 1)` means 6 rows 1 column. That is probably the issue you have there.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Return1Dimension() As String()
    Dim arr(1 To 3) As String

    arr(1) = "First"
    arr(2) = "Second"
    arr(3) = "Third"

    Return1Dimension = arr
End Function



Public Function Return2Dimensions() As String()
    Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 1) As String

    arr(1, 1) = "First"
    arr(2, 1) = "Second"
    arr(3, 1) = "Third"

    Return2Dimensions = arr
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer to the question, but note that you can **write** a single row from VBA --> worksheet with a 1D array.  eg `[c1:l1] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)` works.  The converse is **not** true in that `v = [c1:l1]` will produce a 2D array.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, you are right! I assumed that a list of files in a row doesn't make much sense. In addition to what you say you can also write a 1D array into a column if you transpose it: `Range("A1:A10").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0))`

Comment: Yes, and transposing a 1D array creates a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks, understood! For my purposes I ended up just using =TRANSPOSE(....)
But learnt something today guys.